# consulting file in swi prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I am having issues using the consult predicate. I have altered the folder in which my SWI Prolog starts in (similar to how I did with ML) and save my file in that folder. However, when I use `consult(filename)` which in this example would be `consult(chapter9)` - I get a file does not exist error.

I've Googled around to see if there is a specific place to save it and did not find an answer. I then tried to specify a `pathname` as follows: `consult(C:\chapter9)`. However, this did not work either. I'm quite lost.

Comment: try `consult('C:\\chapter9.pl')` or `consult('C:/chapter9.pl')`

Comment: @CapelliC out of curiosity, why do you offer your answer as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @CapelliC, good question from aBathologist.